# Importing a GitHub library into java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, github, import

I have researched the internet extensively but still cannot figure out how to properly import a GitHub source code library into my java project in eclipse and use it successfully. I can do this perfectly if the library is in a jar format, but I don't know how to do it with source code provided in GitHub. I have tried everything from maven to downloading a zip file with the source code and manually putting it in my code (I know this is terrible practice). It seems like the library I am downloading references other libraries and this chain seems to go on for a long time. 

I have had trouble with all libraries but this one is an example: https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/parse4j

I am relatively new to this kind of stuff, so can someone provide a detail step by step guide on how to do this?

Thank you so much! 
Akarsh.

Comment: Can you include library link in question?

Comment: @NitishkumarSingh yea I just edited my post to include a link

Comment: Create a maven project and then add the [dependency](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/parse4j#maven)

Answer (score 0):

Download the [parse4j](https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/parse4j) github project into same directory as your project. Refer below screenshot
[image: Folder structure]

add `<dependencies></dependencies>` section of the **pom.xml** of your project, in the above image, it's ***jparse***.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.thiagolocatelli</groupId>
   <artifactId>parse4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you will be able to use **parse4j** classes in your project.